# google maps api v2 - dynamic load (tens of thousands of) markers

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

how made with JavaScript+PHP+MYSQL and Google Maps API v2 dynamic load of markers?

atm I have map follow example

http://googlemapsapi.martinpearman.co.uk/infusions/google_maps_api/basic_page.php?map_id=8

but my marker_data_01.php (where are all markers listed -> look code of example) have atm 4MB and will only have more, and more.

So the question is: how load only this markers to `marker_data_01.php` (of some other modification of it, can be on same file as map, meaningless, I load it all from MySQL atm)

what I look now:
so for *example* (I dont know what number will good but I write this only for show what I wanna made OR JUST something like it), so

- top left corner for example have position: 10,
- top right corner for example have position: 30,
- bottom left corner for example have position: 5,
- bottom right corner for example have position: 15.

-- so load only this markers what are in this box 10-30-5-15

with for example GET,

and when I move map for example to 17-12-48-20 box then made next GET request
and with this mysql quote and download next markers that what I see now,

with this I can have map with unlimited markers,

and when will be a lot of markers then clustering can link them,

so with this ppl dont will need do "preload" of all markers DB (what have 4mb now and will have more), but only download that what they see at the moment,

I know that is possible because a lot sites have it but I am not master of code langs, I know only a bit php and mysql (and html) :)

// sorry for my english

Comment: someone know maybe how do that with my script (look bottom comment)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you're looking for something like [MarkerClusterer](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/04/markerclusterer-solution-to-too-many.html)

### EDIT

I see - I didn't get the original ask very clearly.

What you need to do is send the current lat/lon box to the server, and use those values in your WHERE clause.

Here's a quick example

```
// Create a GMap2 instance
var gmap = new GMap2( document.getElementById( 'map' );

// Do all your setup here, like gmap.setCenter() and such

// Now, load the map data
loadMapFromCurrentBounds( gmap );

// Assign a handler to the "moveend" event
GEvent.addListener( gmap, 'moveend', function()
{
  loadMapFromCurrentBounds( gmap );
});

function loadMapFromCurrentBounds( gmap )
{
  // First, determine the map bounds
  var bounds = gmap.getBounds();

  // Then the points
  var swPoint = bounds.getSouthWest();
  var nePoint = bounds.getNorthEast();

  // Now, each individual coordinate
  var swLat = swPoint.lat();
  var swLng = swPoint.lng();
  var neLat = nePoint.lat();
  var neLng = nePoint.lng();

  // Now, build a query-string to represent this data
  var qs = 'swLat=' + swLat + '&swLng=' + swLng + '&neLat=' + neLat + '&neLng=' + neLng;

  // Now you can use this query-string in your AJAX request  

  // AJAX-stuff here
}
```

And then, on the PHP end, assuming your data table has a `lat` and `lng` column, something like this

```
$swLat = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['swLat'] );
$swLng = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['swLng'] );
$neLat = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['neLat'] );
$neLng = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['neLng'] );

$query = "
SELECT *
  FROM [Table]
 WHERE lat > $swLat
   AND lat < $neLat
   AND lng > $swLng
   AND lng < $neLng
";
```

Comment: No, because this is same as I have now http://googlemapsapi.martinpearman.co.uk/infusions/google_maps_api/basic_page.php?map_id=8 (maybe this what I have now is better) so MarkerClusterer need download all markers too - http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/data.json - load it with <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script> so that is same, problem is that - I have at the moment 4MB that file, and will have only more, and more, so that on localhost/Lan load 25sec, so I need some dynamic load, what will DOWNload only markers  what i see

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/ybau9ce - that is my database, try load it with markclusterer will be same, because problem is not with java and load all to memory, because clusterer what I have now help same as that markclusterer, so problem is with download, preload all before will show on map <- that is problem, so I need download only that markers info what i see now, when I move I download next info about markers what I see now etc etc, no all preload, because when I will have 1mln markers with info that will take 10min...

Comment: Added detail to my answer based on your comments.

Comment: on 99% that is it! but I am code-noob... maybe you know how add it to my script what I made -> http://pastebin.com/edAkecJG and my database mysql looks like -> http://pastebin.com/iEBjCbXG

Comment: and my marker json (all db there is, 4mb!) http://tinyurl.com/ybau9ce (i have there for example custom icons what are define in file nodeicon.js)

Comment: do you know maybe how do it :<? I try to do it and still all don't work, probably because I do it bad ;[

Comment: // Now you can use this query-string in your AJAX request  
  // AJAX-stuff here

HOW?

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to generate an AJAX request *at all*?  If that's the case, I suggest you open a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632025/google-maps-api-v2-dynamic-load-tens-of-thousands-of-markers

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to manage/display thousands of markers on google maps using Marker Manager, the performance will be atrocious.  The only way to do this with any reliability is to use either a utility like MarkerClusterer, which groups markers in close proximity together, or use a Fusion Tables Layer.

I personally would recommend the Fusion Tables Layer, however there is a great writeup here that talks about all of the different options that you might want to consider. https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers